# Can QuickBooks Desktop integrate with Mobile Apps?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I need to develop android/ iOS apps using Xamarin which would integrate with QuickBooks Desktop. I need people to be able to access their company file, and update their time from the mobile app.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find much information on it. I would really appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You'd probably be better off using Quickbooks Online REST services with a mobile application. Otherwise it could be possible to create a Desktop application that listens for a request from your mobile app and then uses the Quickbooks SDK to make read/writes to the local environment.

Comment: Thanks @JonDouglas. Would that only work if the clients are using QuickBooks online as opposed to Desktop?

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure Online is a web based platform compared to Desktop which is a local platform. Either way, there is a way to integrate a mobile application with Quickbooks.

Comment: Thanks @JonDouglas I think I'm going to end up using the QB Web Connector